# I think I am unable to relock my postgres psql account

Tags: password, ubuntu-18.04, psql

When I was setting up postgresql on linux, I was following a tutorial that I think had me change the postgres account password and I did not know any better. Please forgive my ignorance.

When I type "psql postgres" it asks for a password and only one password works. I have tried following previous answers by implementing "sudo passwd --lock postgres" and "sudo -u postgres psql postgres" with "\password postgres" and setting a new password (which does not work).

I am afraid to edit /etc/passwd and put * instead of the password because that comment has very few upvotes and I don't know what it will actually do.

Everything I try (even changing md5 to trust in pg_hba.conf), after I enter "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart", psql postgres STILL REQUIRES a password and it only accepts the one password that works. Anything else returns 'psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed'.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Authentication method "peer"

If your authentication method is `peer` like

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

and/or

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

in `pg_hba.conf`, then connect as linux user `postgres` to the database.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

You won't need a password, even if set.

**Note:** `psql -U postgres postgres` run as a different linux user as `postgres` does not work in this case and fails with `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`.

### Authentication method "md5"

If your authentication method is `md5`, then you will need the correct password to connect.

### Reset password

1. Comment all existing lines starting with "local" in `pg_hba.conf` and add line

   ```
   local    all             postgres                               trust
   ```
2. Restart postgres

   ```
   service postgresql restart
   ```
3. Connect to database

   ```
   # as any linux user
   psql -U postgres
   # or as user postgres
   sudo -u postgres psql
   ```
4. Change password

   ```
   ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
   ```
5. Exit

   ```
   \q
   ```
6. Restore your changes in `pg_hba.conf`, default for postgresql 9.6 on Debian 9.8.0 is

   ```
   # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
   local   all             postgres                                peer

   # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

   # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
   local   all             all                                     peer
   # IPv4 local connections:
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
   # IPv6 local connections:
   host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
   # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
   # replication privilege.
   #local   replication     postgres                                peer
   #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
   #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
   ```
7. Restart postgres

   ```
   service postgresql restart
   ```

**Note 2:**
If you want to change the password for a `host` record, then do the same as above by using method `trust` and connect with the hostname option using `psql -U postgres -h localhost postgres`.